# Why can I call a func from a type in Go?

Tags: function, go, methods

I'm learning go and while doing the "A Tour of Go" I've found the following piece of code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    switch {
    case t.Hour() < 12:
        fmt.Println("Good morning!")
    case t.Hour() < 17:
        fmt.Println("Good afternoon.")
    default:
        fmt.Println("Good evening.")
    }
}
```

I want to know what I'm doing, so I opened up the documentation regarding the "time" package.

When doing `t := time.Now()`, as per documentation, I get a type struct Time (https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Now), but then, to get the Hour we do `t.Hour()`.
I would understand if t was an instance of object Time and Hour a method from this object, but this is not oop, and t is a type, and I would expect to call it like `time.Hour(t)` to get the hour.

Could you give me some light on why `t.Hour()` works?

Thanks!
/Miguel

Comment: "I get a type struct Time" No. Plain wrong. You get back a **value** with type time.Time. You can call methods on these values. Your `t` is what you would call an "instance of type time.Time` in C++, Java or C#.

Comment: If you want an analogy from oops then t.Now() is creating an instance of the class time and t.Hour() etc are methods defined on it .

Comment: Calling a method from a type is a different concept, called a [method expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`t` is not a type, it is a variable holding a struct value of type `time.Time` returned by the `time.Now()` function.

`t.Hour()` calls the `Time.Hour()` method with `t` receiver.